# Dominating of an integral function as the variant converges to\infty

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Given $h(t)∈C^1(R)$,and tending to zero as $|t|\to\infty$ at the rate $O(t^{-2})$,
let $f(ζ)$ defined by
$$f(ζ)=\frac{1}{πi}\int_{R}{\frac{h(t)}{t-ζ}}dt$$ 
If we restrict $f$ to the upper plane,
show that $$|f(ζ)|=o(|ζ|^{-1})$$ as $|ζ|\to \infty$.

It is obvious if $h$ is a restriction of an analytic function on the upper half-plane.But I don't know how to restrict it well for just such a $h∈C^1(R)$.I need help!

Comment: Try integration by parts: $\int \frac{h'(t)}{(t-\zeta)^2}$ is $O(|\zeta|^{-2})$, and the boundary terms can be dealt with.

Comment: @NormalHuman Would you please write it as an answer?I cannot understand you clearly.